# Installing grub for ubuntu 14.04 from ubuntu 13.10 Live DVD

Tags: 14.04, grub2, 13.10, mbr

I had installed windows 7 recently and thereby lost my grub. but my Linux partition is still there... I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed previously. I want to reinstall the grub from a live CD.But I don't have the live CD of ubuntu 14.04, I only have the live CD of ubuntu 13.10... is it okay to install grub from it?

Comment: Try boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair, it is made for just this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to install the GRUB from 13.10 for 14.04. In fact, any distro which is using GRUB2 should be fine for use. However, as long as the Ubuntu installtion is present, you can use the `grub` utilities from it to install GRUB. From a live CD/USB, do:

```bsh
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt 

sudo mount /dev/ /mnt/dev -o bind
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do
    sudo mount -B $i /mnt/$i;
done 

sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash -l

# From here on you're in the Ubuntu chroot, logged in as root.
grub-install /dev/sda 
update-grub
exit # exit the chroot
```

Of course, use the correct the partitions/disks in place of `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sda1`. Use the `lsblk` command or the GParted application to find out, if you're not sure.